# Can't track memory issues from valgrind

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I think I have more than one issue in the code that is causing memory issues. I've commented the parts I've been able to track. I think I'm having some issues with the pointers, what to use where, and maybe some other minor issues.

**My main code**

```
     int main(int argc, char ** argv){
        printf("In Main\n");
        if(argc != 7){
            printf("args doesn't match expected value\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if(fptr == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        long int size_compressed; //size_compressed: Number of bytes in compressed file
        long int size_topology;   //size_topology: Number of bytes topology uses
        long int size_original;   //size_original: Number of bytes in the uncompressed file
    
        fread(&size_compressed, sizeof(long int) , 1, fptr);
        fread(&size_topology, sizeof(long int), 1, fptr);
        fread(&size_original, sizeof(long int), 1, fptr);
        int size = sizeof(char)* sizeof(long int) * size_topology;
    
        printf("Size Compressed: %ld\n", size_compressed);
        printf("Size Topology: %ld\n", size_topology);
        printf("Size Original: %ld\n", size_original);
        
        unsigned char *buffer;
        int *val; 
        buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * size_topology);
        size_t bytes_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), size_topology, fptr);
        //val = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (size_topology));
        val = (int*) malloc(size);
        fclose(fptr);
    
        if(bytes_read != size_topology){
            printf("Topology size and read bytes don't match!");
        }
    
        for(int i=0; i < size_topology; i++){
          val[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    
        char *toVal; //toVal: char array of 8 to store every bit of a byte
        char *all_topology;  //all_topology: char array of 8 * size_topology to store ALL bits of topology. 
        int j; //j: index for all_topology
        // toVal = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* sizeof(int));
        // all_topology = (char*) malloc(size);
        toVal = (char*) malloc(size);
        all_topology = (char*) malloc(size);
    
        //For Loop where conversion of the bytes in val to bits happen, output is stored in all_topology 
        for(int i=0; i < size_topology; i++){
            j = i*8;
            byte_to_bits(val[i], toVal);
            for(int k=0; k< 8;k++){
                all_topology[j] = toVal[k];
                printf("%d", all_topology[j]);
                j++;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        //no memory issues up to here

    Snode* stack = NULL;
    int numOfBytes = byte_to_char(all_topology, &stack, size);
    Tnode* tmp = NULL;
    while(1){
        if(isEmpty(stack)){
            break;
        } else{
            tmp = pop(&stack);
        }
    }
    remove_zeroes(stack);
    printf("NumOfBYtes: %d\n", numOfBytes);
    Tnode* node;
    Snode* reverse_stack;
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag){
        node = pop(&stack);
        if(node == NULL){
            break;
        }
        printf("%c\n", node->id);
        push(&reverse_stack, node); 
    }
    // printf("\n");


    // Snode* tmp = reverse_stack;
    // while(reverse_stack != NULL){
    //     char a = peek(&tmp);
    //     printf("%c", a);
    //     tmp = tmp->next;
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    // Topolgy created in the same format as pg6 line1. into stack "reverse_stack"
    // Lots of memory errors and memory lost
    // Still need to build tree



    //free(node);
    free(all_topology);
    free(toVal);
    // free(node);
    free(buffer);
    free(val);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Valgrind output**

```
==10990== 
==10990== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10990==     in use at exit: 552 bytes in 23 blocks
==10990==   total heap usage: 53 allocs, 30 frees, 1,778 bytes allocated
==10990== 
==10990== Searching for pointers to 23 not-freed blocks
==10990== Checked 70,128 bytes
==10990== 
==10990== 168 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==10990==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==10990==    by 0x400D53: createNode (tree.c:9)
==10990==    by 0x400868: byte_to_char (pa2.c:46)
==10990==    by 0x400C4A: main (pa2.c:152)
==10990== 
==10990== 192 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==10990==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==10990==    by 0x400D53: createNode (tree.c:9)
==10990==    by 0x40089B: byte_to_char (pa2.c:52)
==10990==    by 0x400C4A: main (pa2.c:152)
==10990== 
==10990== 192 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==10990==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==10990==    by 0x400D53: createNode (tree.c:9)
==10990==    by 0x400941: byte_to_char (pa2.c:69)
==10990==    by 0x400C4A: main (pa2.c:152)
==10990== 
==10990== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10990==    definitely lost: 552 bytes in 23 blocks
==10990==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10990==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10990==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10990==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10990== 
==10990== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Based on the valgrind output, I have also added the functions mentioned in the errors below.

**byte_to_char**

```
int byte_to_char(char *topology, Snode** stack, int size){
    int numOfBytes = 0;
    char ascii_concat[8]; 
    unsigned char ascii_val = 0;  
    int countChar =0;
    Tnode* node;
    //char char_top[80];
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
        if(topology[i] == 0){
            //char_top[i] = 48; //ASCII Value of 0
            node = createNode(48, 0);
            push(stack, node);
            numOfBytes++;
        } else{
            ascii_val = 0xff;
            //char_top[i] = 49; //ASCII Value of 1
            node = createNode(49, 1);
            push(stack, node);
            numOfBytes++;
            i++; //skip the leaf node indicator
            countChar++;  
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                ascii_concat[j] = topology[i++];
            }
            i--;
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                if(ascii_concat[j] == 0){
                    ascii_val = (1 << (j)) ^ ascii_val;
                }
            }
            //printf("%c\n", ascii_val);
            //Create leaf node
            //char_top[i] = ascii_val;
            node = createNode(ascii_val, 2);
            push(stack, node);
            numOfBytes = numOfBytes+8;
            //count characters in header
        }
        countChar++;
    }

    // printf("chars\n");
    // for(int i=0;i < 24; i++){
    //    printf("%c", char_top[i]);
    // }
    free(node);
    return numOfBytes;
    
}
```

**CreateNode**

```
Tnode *createNode(int key, int bal)
{
    Tnode *n = (Tnode *)calloc(1, sizeof(Tnode));
    //Tnode *n = (Tnode*) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    n->key = key;
    n->balance = bal;
    n->left = NULL;  //?
    n->right = NULL; //?
    return n;
}
```

Comment: There may be more problems, but your `createNote()` function is returning the memory address of a local variable, which goes out of scope on return. You need to instead pass in a pointer to be allocated that exists outside of `createNode()`, so your definition should look like: `Tnode *createNode(Tnode *n, int key, int bal)`. Declare the new `Tnode` prior to the call to `createNode()`, pass it in, then recover the allocated memory from the return value. Typically you would also pass in at least one of the `left` or `right` pointers as well and point to them inside the `createNode()` function,

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Basically I would need to re-structure how I create my nodes?

Comment: you cannot return the memory address of a variable declared inside the function that is returning. Dereferencing the pointer in the caller is undefined behavior.

Comment: Please don't delete the code from your question; the question doesn't make sense without it.

Answer (score 0):

In your function byte_to_char in your for loop you allocate memory 3 times when you call your createNode function. But this memory is never freed so valgrind signals memory leaks. You must free your node variable in the loop otherwise every time you change the value of the pointer you will lose the address and you will not be able to free the memory.

Because you can't free in the loop, maybe you should send a duplication of your node and then free your node variable

```
Tnode *my_duplicate_node(const Tnode *src)
{
    Tnode *dest = calloc(sizeof(Tnode), 1);

    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(Tnode));
    return dest;
}

for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
    if(topology[i] == 0){
        node = createNode(48, 0);
        push(stack, my_duplicate_node(node));
        free(node);
    } else{
        [...]
        node = createNode(49, 1);
        push(stack, my_duplicate_node(node));
        free(node);
    }
}
```

It doesn't exist any function to duplicate a memory block for a structure so you can try something like this my_duplicate_node function

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it gave a similar error in the end. 3 errors, still at createNode, 576 bytes lost.

.
.
.

192 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==31508==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==31508==    by 0x400DD5: createNode (tree.c:9)
==31508==    by 0x4009CF: byte_to_char (pa2.c:71)
==31508==    by 0x400CCC: main (pa2.c:153)
==31508== 
==31508== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31508==    definitely lost: 576 bytes in 24 blocks
==31508== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts

Comment: [UPDATE]: I missed a free. This is the most recent error. 2 errors, still at createNode, 384 bytes lost. Total heap usage: 69 allocs, 53 frees, 2,162 bytes allocated. -----HEAP SUMMARY----- 192 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==31814==    at 0x4C2C089: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==31814==    by 0x400E1A: duplicate_node (tree.c:18)
==31814==    by 0x4008D8: byte_to_char (pa2.c:47)
==31814==    by 0x400CD8: main (pa2.c:154)

Comment: Now you should free your linked list at the end of the program to remove last memory leaks